# different behaviour of mkstemp between windows and linux

Tags: windows, gcc, mingw, libc, mkstemp

The following small application will behave differently on Linux and Windows.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char template[100];

int main()
{
  strncpy(template, "stXXXXXX", 11);
  mkstemp(template);
  printf("%s\n", template);
  return 0;
}
```

When simply executed multiple times it will produce the expected result (ie. a different file with a random name) on both Windows and Linux.
However, if we also remove the generated file after each execution:

- on Linux it will produce the expected result
- on Windows it will produce the same file

[image]

On both Linux and Windows I used the latest gcc 13. For Windows I have used the release from winlibs.

Do you have any idea why that is?

Comment: I guess it's because the mingw version [uses `rand()`](https://github.com/mingw-w64/mingw-w64/blob/master/mingw-w64-crt/misc/mkstemp.c#L48), and no-one called `srand()`.